# Ruby "gem" command fails with Permission denied @ rb_sysopen

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

Something seems to be broken with my "gem" command. Here's what I get on running "gem"

> /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/stub_specification.rb:114:in
>   `initialize': Permission denied @ rb_sysopen -
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/specifications/unicode-display_width-1.4.1.gemspec
>   (Errno::EACCES)   from
>   /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/stub_specification.rb:114:in`
>   open'    from
>   /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/stub_specification.rb:114:in
>   `data'    from
>   /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/stub_specification.rb:204:in`
>   valid?'  from
>   /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:774:in
>   `select'  from
>   /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:774:in`
>   gemspec_stubs_in'    from
>   /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:798:in `block
>   in map_stubs'     from
>   /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:795:in`each'
>     from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:795:in
>   `flat_map'    from
>   /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:795:in`
>   map_stubs'   from
>   /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:788:in
>   `installed_stubs'     from
>   /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:826:in`
>   stubs'   from
>   /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:747:in `_all'
>     from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1131:in`
>   latest_specs'    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:546:in
>   `find_latest_files'   from
>   /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:1111:in`load_plugins'
>     from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:86:in
>   `<top (required)>'    from
>   /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in`
>   require'     from
>   /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in
>   `require'     from /usr/bin/gem:9:in`'

However the command runs fine if I do "sudo gem".

The bigger problem is that I am not able to use "bundle" to install new gems(e.g., fastlane). Note that I am using "bundle update" to install a gem via a Gemfile. And that **fails with the exact same stack trace** as the one posted above.

How can I fix this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Install RVM with `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`; install Ruby with `rvm install 2.5.3`. [Don't](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/psa-do-not-use-system-ruby) [use](https://chrisherring.co/posts/why-you-shouldn-t-use-the-system-ruby) [system Ruby](http://billpatrianakos.me/blog/2014/05/15/never-use-system-ruby-ever/).

Comment: While you’d better use any of ruby version manager, like suggested by @anothermh, you might fix the issue with `chown -R \`whoami\` /usr/local/lib/site_ruby`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get this error when you run without sudo because you're using what some people refer to as "system" ruby on your computer; it's the default ruby that ships with macOS. If you run `which ruby` it will most likely point to `/usr/bin/ruby` (if you haven't installed `rvm`, `rbenv`, or another ruby version manager.

By default, system ruby (which includes the system `gem` and `bundler` commmands) points to a file location which requires `sudo` to install to.

I recommend you don't run sudo to install gems; instead install a ruby version manager such as [rvm](https://rvm.io/) (the most popular), [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) (also a popular choice), or [asdf](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf) (my preferred version manager because it manages more than just ruby, if you want to)

Once you install a ruby version manager per the instructions you should be able to install a more recent version of ruby (system ruby is 2.3.7, the most recent is 2.6.0). The version manager will also setup sane paths for your `gem` and `bundle` commands, pointing to paths where you have write privileges without using `sudo`

A ruby version manager is highly recommended *for local development* because it won't interfere with any system dependencies which might rely on the system ruby version, and a version manager allows you to install multiple versions of ruby and switch between them for different projects.

Comment: ruby version manager may not be ideal in production

Comment: I would agree with that statement, generally. I'll update my answer to say "highly recommended for local development". Running sudo commands is also generally not ideal in production (for installing gems) and I assumed the OP is doing all of this locally.

Comment: Your answer still makes the assumption the OP's problem is on a local development environment and doesn't address how to solve this for other environments. You may also want to update mentions of "most recent is 2.6.0" as that is way out of date. Finally, suggest that you remove opinion based commentary like "my preferred version manager because".  What versions the users "should be able to install" may also depend on their OS and system architecture.  For example M1 cannot install any version of Ruby < 2.7 and you don't know which version the OP may need for their project.

Comment: @lacostenycoder You should feel free to add another alternative answer that deals with your concerns